# ng2-file-upload support Angular 16

Tags: angular, web, web-development-server, ng2-file-upload

I have ng2-file-upload installed in my angular project and I am using angular 16. The following is blocking me

This likely means that the library (ng2-file-upload) which declares FileUploadModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue while migration. I used ng2-file-upload version 3.0.0 which solved my issue. But make sure to add url in fileUploaderOptions which is made mandatory.